# nullable bool is being passed to the controller null all the time regardless of the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass a nullable bool to my controller. But when I pass the bool value from my view to the controller, it's being passed null all the time regardless of the value it has in my view.

Here is my view:

```
@model Cars.Models.Car

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
new { id = "CategoryFormID"})) {
    <label>Convertible:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ConvertibleID" name="convertible"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" id="SubmitID">Search</button>
}
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(bool? convertible){
    var cars = from d in db.Car
               select d;

    if (convertible.HasValue)
        {
            cars = cars.Where(x => x.Convertible == convertible);
        }

    return View("SearchResult", cars);
}
```

I also have other fields such as drop down lists and text fields, but they're being passed flawless. Any help would be really appreciated.

Update:
Thank you for your fast responds. However, I did try giving it a value="True" as you guys suggested. There is only 2 options now: null and true. But my intention is to use nullable bool to have three options: null (when user doesn't touch the checkbox), true(checked) and false(unchecked). I know it sounds not smart and silly, but I'm just trying to figure out how nullable bool is working, and what is the intention of having such a thing in C# (I'm new with C#).
I was wondering if it is possible to do so with just checkbox and without the use of dropdownlist or radio buttons.

Comment: Try assigning the attribute `value="true"` to the input tag.

Comment: this is mvc behavior,but you need to implement custom binder for this purpose. tel me if some examples make you happy.

Comment: Examples would be really great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 give a value in your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="True" id="ConvertibleID" name="convertible"/>
```

Comment: Tried, it works when I check it, but when I unchecked the checkbox it passes the value as null. Then isn't there any way to have three values for it? if not, then what's the point of nullable bool? Thank you.

Comment: the point is you are using a checkbox checkbox has only two options it either true when it checked or null/false when it not cheked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take it from request

```
Request.Form["convertible"]
```